# Is there a way to copy only the structure (not the data) of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I received a DataFrame from somewhere and want to create another DataFrame with the same number and names of columns and rows (indexes). For example, suppose that the original data frame was created as

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[11,12],[21,22]], columns=['c1','c2'], index=['i1','i2'])
```

I copied the structure by explicitly defining the columns and names:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
```

I don't want to copy the data, otherwise I could just write `df2 = df1.copy()`. In other words, after df2 being created it must contain only NaN elements:

```
In [1]: df1
Out[1]: 
    c1  c2
i1  11  12
i2  21  22

In [2]: df2
Out[2]: 
     c1   c2
i1  NaN  NaN
i2  NaN  NaN
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing it?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way than what you tried, you could also just create an empty df with the structure you want and copy it, this does seem to me to be less performant than creating the df with your data and structure you desire in a single operation

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion EdChum, but this piece of code receive the original DataFrame from somewhere else. I will edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I still think there isn't a better method and it's pretty clear your intentions as you pass no data to the constructor

Answer (score 79, accepted):

That's a job for [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html). Start with the original:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[11, 12], [21, 22]], columns=['c1', 'c2'], index=['i1', 'i2'])
```

Construct an empty DataFrame and reindex it like df1:

```
pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df1)
Out: 
    c1  c2
i1 NaN NaN
i2 NaN NaN
```

Comment: Never seen `reindex_like`, so happy to see something new

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. It not only keep the column and the row names, but also the type of the columns, without the need to explicitly copying these properties.  Also, I think it is very efficient since it starts with an empty DataFrame followed by one resizing operation.

Comment: This is much faster than the explicit solution. In my case by 20x.

Comment: Unlike @bmello , when I do `pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df1).dtypes` on my DataFrame with column types: `datetime64[ns]`, `int64`, and `object`, everything is turned into `float64`. Version `0.24.2` of Pandas.

Comment: This does indded _not_ keep the dtypes. Use: new_df = dataframe.copy(deep=False);   new_df.astype(dataframe.dtypes.to_dict()).

Comment: @Phlogi could you please explain why you do a shallow copy and then the `new_df.astype...` statement?

Answer (score 64):

In [version 0.18 of pandas, the DataFrame constructor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) has no options for creating a dataframe like another dataframe with NaN instead of the values.

The code you use `df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)` is the most logical way, the only way to improve on it is to spell out even more what you are doing is to add `data=None`, so that other coders directly see that you intentionally leave out the data from this new DataFrame you are creating.

TLDR: So my suggestion is:

#### Explicit is better than implicit

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
```

Very much like yours, but more spelled out.

Comment: This doesn't preserve column type. Any suggestions?

Comment: @dbc I doubt pandas respects dtypes with an empty dataset, but I updated my answer for to match my best guess. I also have to say that pandas does nothing to enforce dtypes and I get the feeling you may think setting them will provide some extra usability. dtypes are a numpy thing and are automagically changed outside of the control of pandas whenever it suits numpy.

Comment: unfortunately `pd.DataFrame` only accepts one default dtype in its constructor. Without it, and setting `data=None`, all columns are dtype object. This matters because I eventually want to call `df2.to_sql`, which doesn't play well with object columns. Of course, I could manually set each dtype in my `to_sql` call, but it would be better if it came from df1 during the structural copy.

Comment: @dbc Yes, you're right, pandas only takes a single dtype on construction. Generally I would advice against building SQL tables based on dtypes as dtypes carry far far less information than a properly defined SQL table needs.

Comment: I agree, I construct my tables with SQL create statements, and then use `df.to_sql(..., if_exists='append', index=False)`. But when I do that to a df created with this structure-copy method, the insert fails because of the object dtype. My workaround is to manually call `pd.to_numeric` (etc) on each column. I was hoping there was a more generic method, but it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 24):

### Not exactly answering this question, but a similar one for people coming here via a search engine

My case was creating a copy of the **data frame without data and without index**. One can achieve this by doing the following. This will maintain the dtypes of the columns.

```
empty_copy = df.drop(df.index)
```

Comment: Combining bits and pieces mostly from existing comments (for sake of that 'similar case'): `empty_copy = df.head(0).copy()`  or (from another answer below, but 2 characters longer...): `empty_copy = df.iloc[0:0].copy()`.

This is more efficient (doesn't arrive to an empty set from a large set) and detaches the copy from the original object. Seems this is how far the `dtypes` can be kept, `.reindex()` or the kind will forget about them. (Though as many point out, `dtype` is not as robust so not as valuable as one would first think or hope.)

Comment: I like this answer because it preserves the type of columns

Answer (score 13):

### Let's start with some sample data

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']],
   ...:                   columns=['num', 'char'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   num char
0    1    a
1    2    b
2    3    c

In [4]: df.dtypes
Out[4]: 
num      int64
char    object
dtype: object
```

#### Now let's use a simple `DataFrame` initialization using the columns of the original `DataFrame` but providing no data:

```
In [5]: empty_copy_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df.columns)

In [6]: empty_copy_1
Out[6]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [num, char]
Index: []

In [7]: empty_copy_1.dtypes
Out[7]: 
num     object
char    object
dtype: object
```

As you can see, the column data types are not the same as in our original `DataFrame`.

#### So, if you want to preserve the column `dtype`...

If you want to preserve the column data types you need to construct the `DataFrame` one `Series` at a time

```
In [8]: empty_copy_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([
   ...:     (name, pd.Series(data=None, dtype=series.dtype))
   ...:     for name, series in df.iteritems()])

In [9]: empty_copy_2
Out[9]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [num, char]
Index: []

In [10]: empty_copy_2.dtypes
Out[10]: 
num      int64
char    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that setting the dtype for an empty column in a dataframe does not change the behavior of the dataframe in any way.

Comment: It might not change the behavior within the pandas framework.  But consumer code might be set up to check data types or column names, and in those cases you would like that code not to have to be written differently or include an if clause for cases when `len(df) == 0`

Answer (score 8):

A simple alternative -- first copy the basic structure or indexes and columns with datatype from the original dataframe (df1) into df2

```
df2 = df1.iloc[0:0]
```

Then fill your dataframe with empty rows -- pseudocode that will need to be adapted to better match your actual structure:

```
s = pd.Series([Nan,Nan,Nan], index=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

loop through the rows in df1

```
df2 = df2.append(s)
```

Comment: Change `df1.iloc[0:0]` to `df1.iloc[0:0].copy()`, because if you don't, you're still working with a reference to `df1`.
This prevents the warning `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame` when doing something like `df2.rename(columns={"c1": "z1"}, inplace=True)`.

Comment: Easiest option here.

Answer (score 5):

To preserve column type you can use the astype method,
like `pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns).astype(df1.dtypes)`

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [11, 12, 'Alice'],
        [21, 22, 'Bob']
    ],
    columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
    index=['i1', 'i2']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns).astype(df1.dtypes)
print(df2.shape)
print(df2.dtypes)
```

output:

```
(0, 3)
c1     int64
c2     int64
c3    object
dtype: object
```

[Working example](https://ideone.com/N1hb41)

Comment: @pedro-m-duarte The [DataFrame.from_items](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_items.html) is deprecated for a long time and no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `mask` by `notna()` i.e

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[11, 12], [21, 22]], columns=['c1', 'c2'], index=['i1', 'i2'])

df2 = df1.mask(df1.notna())

    c1  c2
i1 NaN NaN
i2 NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to copy df structure into df2 is:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in pandas 0.22:
`df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.delete(slice(None)), columns=df.columns)`

Convert types:
`df2 = df2.astype(df.dtypes)`

`delete(slice(None))`
In case you do not want to keep the values ​​of the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would add my two cents.

```
def df_cols_like(df):
    """
    Returns an empty data frame with the same column names and types as df
    """
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({i[0]: pd.Series(dtype=i[1])
                        for i in df.dtypes.iteritems()},
                       columns=df.dtypes.index)
    return df2
```

This approach centers around the `df.dtypes` attribute of the input data frame, `df`, which is a `pd.Series`. A `pd.DataFrame` is constructed from a dictionary of empty `pd.Series` objects named using the input column names with the column order being taken from the input `df`.