# Create a DataFrame based on a shape with default values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that receives a df. 
I'm trying to make it return a df with the same shape but a default value (True in my example).

I will sometimes get a series as a df (one col only).

I managed to find something for a series:

```
def func(df):
    return pd.Series([True for i in range(df.shape[0])])
```

I also managed a for a df:

```
def func(df):
     return df.apply(lambda x: True)
```

but this seems waist-full on resources and Im trying to find a fast and elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: what about `df[:]=True` ?

Comment: interesting. That works, but it changes the df itself and not returning a new df. Any ideas how "expensive" it is, resources wise?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df).fillna(True)` should be pretty efficient. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467730/is-there-a-way-to-copy-only-the-structure-not-the-data-of-a-pandas-dataframe/47961242#47961242

Comment: @ayhan this doesnt work for a series :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 3**: *add %timeit for a few posted answers*

On sample:

```
n = np.arange(900000).reshape(300000, 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(n, columns = list('abc'))
```

%timeit results:

```
In [19]: %timeit pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df).fillna(True)
336 ms ± 13.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [20]: %timeit ~df.eq(np.nan)
2.7 ms ± 175 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit df.where(df.isna()).fillna(True)
332 ms ± 11.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [22]: %%timeit
    ...: df1=df.copy()
    ...: df1[:]=True
    ...:
7.39 ms ± 339 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So, `~df.eq(np.nan)` is the fastest

---

**Edit 2:** add another method using the special feature of 'NaN' which is `NaN == NaN` return `False`. Therefore, compare whole `df` to `NaN`. It will return all `False`. Then, use negation operator `'~'` to turn everything to True

```
~df.eq(np.nan)

Out[1386]:
      a     b     c
0  True  True  True
1  True  True  True
2  True  True  True
```

**Edit**: (*add explanation*)

Document on [df.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where)

`df.isna` returns `True` on `NaN` and `False` on `non-NaN`. I use `df.isna` to create a boolean mask to use with `.where`. On mask `True`, `.where` keeps the same value which is `NaN`. On mask `False`, `.where` replaces with the `replaced-value`. I don't specify `replaced-value`, so `.where` defaults to `NaN`.

It means the whole `df` will turn to all `NaN` no matter what values it has. Finally, `fillna` to `True`

This method works on both dataframe and series

---

IIUC, you want to make a `new_df` from a current `df` where all values turn to `True`. If that is the case, you don't need a function.

A simple way as follows should work:

sample data:

```
df:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

df.where(df.isna()).fillna(True)

Out[1374]:
      a     b     c
0  True  True  True
1  True  True  True
2  True  True  True
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on the answer? df.isna() supposed to return missing values. how does this work on all the values?

Comment: @NotSoShabby: I added another method using `NaN` comparison and negation. Check my update

Comment: `~df.eq(np.nan)` is definitely the most elegant way. do you know if this is also efficient?

Comment: @NotSoShabby: I added `%timeit` for a few answers here. By the results, `~df.eq(np.nan)` is fastest.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rep_values(obj, value):
    obj[:] = value  //Change condition based on your needs
    return obj

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  2  3
In [28]: df = rep_values(df, 1)

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1

In [30]: s = pd.Series([1,2,3])

In [31]: s = rep_values(s, 1)

In [32]: s
Out[32]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Im trying to do it without a condition. just by the shape (e.g I dont mind if its null or not)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the type of data on your `df` there can be multiple way of doing it. However this following method is agnostic of the data type in `df`.

```py
import numpy as np
def create_default_df(df, replace_with):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.full(df.shape,replace_with), columns = df.columns, index = df.index)
```

here is a test case:

```py
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b': ['x', None, 'y']})
default_dat = create_default_df(ser, 0)
print(default_dat)
```

The result is

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  0
2  0  0
```

### Edit - for series

```py
ser = pd.Series([1,2,3])
default_dat = create_default_df(dat, 0)
print(default_dat)
```

and the output is

```
   0
0  0
1  0
2  0
```

Comment: This wouldnt work on a series though :/. it is good for a full DF though

Comment: Have you tried with a series? the function worked fine for me.

Comment: I have added the use case of a series too. As series have no colname (unless you explicitly mention a name), the output will alway name the col as `0`. Check and let me know if this solves your query

Answer (score 1):

You can write a func which takes the `df` as input and returns a `df1` of same shape with values as `True`:

```
def my_true(df):
    df1=df.copy()
    df1[:]=True
    return df1
```

---

```
my_true(df)
```

---

```
      a     b     c
0  True  True  True
1  True  True  True
2  True  True  True
```