# How to get hold of a pyarrow table schema (from a dataframe), copy it into code, and then apply it to new tables?

Tags: pyarrow

A common operation is to get a schema, and use it to create tables and write ParquetWriter. But how to actually *get* the schema, copy paste into the code, and then use it without manually writing a bunch of helper functions? There must be a from json or something?

Comment: table.schema should not be a repl it should be a real thing you can copy paste. All the examples look like manually created code. There is no point?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467730/is-there-a-way-to-copy-only-the-structure-not-the-data-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: There is currently no other way to get a schema than either access it from an actual in-memory object (eg from reading it from a file) or to manually create it using the API (there is no JSON like format for it)